# Согласование определений

Tags: согласование

Как правильно сказать: Поступили деньги из областного и местного бюджета или Поступили деньги из областного и местного бюджетов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь подчёркивается количество бюджетов, то, что деньги пришли и из областного, и из местного бюджетов, значит, лучше употребить множ. число сущ.

Comment: А я считала, что это перечисляемые разновидности предметов, которые внутренне связаны (типа программы для средней и высшей школы). А как же будет дети старшей и младшей группы или групп

Comment: Вот здесь ед.ч.- подходит объяснение внутренняя связь , но нужно всё предложение. Если подчёркивается количество, то ставим во множ.числе:На улице гуляли дети старшей и младшей групп(обе группы), но: Так же ведут себя дети старшей и младшей группы (по отдельности)

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку речь идёт о разных источниках денег (два разных бюджета от разных органов власти), то без повторения предлога "из" указание "бюджета" в единственном числе исказило бы смысл. Появился бы образ единого "областного и местного бюджета", которого на самом деле нет. Если же предлог "из" повторить, то останутcя только вопросы стиля. Вариант с множественным числом выглядит более формальным, но для документа он убедительнее.